# meaning of melon headed

Tags: meaning, idiom-meaning

I know what Melon heads is and I also know that what is Home Run in the context of baseball, but it doesn't help me to understand this sentence: "or the gargantuan power of suddenly melon-headed home-run hitters"

the whole paragraph is this: He wasn’t being hoodwinked
by a phony superperformance, like the “miraculous” endurance of Tour de France cyclists,
or the gargantuan power of suddenly melon-headed home-run hitters, or the blazing
speed of female sprinters who win five medals in one Olympics before going to jail for lying to
the feds about steroids.

Comment: I'd guess it's a variant of (racist) [**pumpkin head**](https://www.definitions.net/definition/pumpkin+head) pumpkin head(Noun) *- an Asian, who are reputed to have big round heads.* Whatever - I'd avoid it.

Comment: @FF '... _suddenly_ melon-headed'?

Comment: You  might want to reconsider your answer selection....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imo it's clearly related to illicit drug use. A melon head is outsized and may also be bald.

Incidentally creatures called ['melon heads'](http://www.the13thfloor.tv/2017/04/26/the-frightening-melon-head-legend-from-ohio-michigan-and-connecticut/) can be found in certain US urban legends (Michigan, Ohio, Conneticut).

> First theorized in the 1970s, melon heads *are said to be completely
>   bald with misshapen bulbous heads*, deformed arms and legs, teeth
>   like daggers, and luminous red eyes.

Human growth hormones can affect the size of one's skull. And anabolic steroids can make one bald. [Here's](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2007/11/could-steroids-have-made-barry-bonds-head-grow-in-size.html) an article focussing on the baseball player Barry Bond's changing hat-size due to doping. Extract:

> Following the federal indictment of Barry Bonds for perjury and
>   obstruction of justice last week, media reports cited the baseball
>   player’s refusal to “admit that steroids contributed to his swollen
>   head and bloated physique,” and drew a line from his alleged use of
>   performance-enhancing drugs to his “noticeably bigger” skull. Can
>   doping really make your head get bigger?

Comment: So, they are suddenly that way due to the doping? Ok, I'll buy that. But it just means a huge head. Your reasoning is right, your reference is not.

Comment: I'm not sure why the reference is wrong. I gave the link for a description and  pictures of what this kind of head might look like. But maybe you thought I was making some kind of etymological claim. I've added an 'incidentally' to make sure it's not ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

An interpretation based on some indirect references.

A melon is a large head. Another way to say that  is to have a **big head** is a person with a huge ego or personality. **When you hit a home run in baseball, that can give you a "big head".** Any major accomplishment can give a person a big head.

So, **suddenly melon-headed home-run hitters**, are baseball players who suddenly got a big head from hitting home runs and who had probably not distinguished themselves before that.

**CUBS PITCHER NAILS GIANTS HITTER RIGHT IN THE MELON**

Giants left fielder, Nori Aoki, exited Sunday's game vs. the Chicago Cubs at Wrigley Field after being hit by a pitch in the helmet.

In the top of the third inning, Aoki was facing Jake Arrieta when his 0-1 pitch sailed high and smacked him on the right side of his helmet. **Aoki attempted to get out of the way and was still beaned, though his attempt may have caused the pitch to not hit him square in the face.**

[melon + pitching + baseball](https://classicrock1069.com/cubs-pitcher-nails-giants-hitter-right-in-the-melon/)

Game of Shadows
**How Barry Bonds became the melon-head he is today, and why baseball is to blame.**

In that article, it means a huge head.

[Barry Bonds +melon-head](http://Game%20of%20Shadows%20How%20Barry%20Bonds%20became%20the%20melon-head%20he%20is%20today,%20and%20why%20baseball%20is%20to%20blame.)

First off, the prosecutors will run with what we all saw using the ‘ol eye ball test: Barry Bonds’ melon grew to humongous sizes. Recent pictures of Bonds revealed that Baroid has shrunk like a deflated balloon from the days when he was ruling baseball. He went from a skinny kid who could hit to a superhuman baseball cartoon version of the Incredible Hulk, complete with a gigantic melon. Prosecutors are expected to have Mike Murphy, the Giants clubhouse manager, testify that Baroid’s hat size increased during his time in San Francisco — and not because of his increased ego.

[baseball + melon](https://larrybrownsports.com/baseball/barry-bonds-increased-head-and-foot-size-part-of-prosecutions-perjury-case/57626)

Another way of saying the same thing: 
He wasn’t being hoodwinked by the gargantuan power of getting a big head from hitting home runs.

Comment: The paragraph quoted in the question is specifically about athletic performances that are enhanced by drugs or steroids - did you want to address that angle at all? Also, your example with "right in the melon" doesn't seem to have any implication of either a physically or figurative large head.

Comment: The main point is that melon= head or big head. Drugs can give someone that feeling as can hitting a home run. He wasn't being hoodwinked by that: having a big head due to hitting home runs. The term here is not about drugs per se. It's about getting a big head from hitting home runs.

Comment: The Barry Bonds article you link to isn't a metaphorical feeling of having a big head due to a good performance; it means Barry Bonds head physically grew in size as a pharmacological side effect.

Comment: @user662852 Who said that? The Barry Bonds article shows that **melon means a big head**.  mellon-headed is adjectival just like big-headed would be. You get a big head (mellon head) from batting home runs. Geesus. It's so simple.

Comment: "... Mike Murphy, the Giants clubhouse manager, testify that Baroid’s hat size increased during his time in San Francisco", as stated in your answer.

Comment: This is clearly the correct answer. The expression is figurative, not literal. If it *were* literal, it would apply to shape as well as size, and there are obviously different sizes and shapes of melons. And thinking that melons are bald is simply bizarre.